# how to display graph with Bokeh in django for stocks

Tags: python, django, graph, linear-regression, bokeh

I m using linear regression to predict the closing price of a stock on the current day. This works fine.
I m using Django.

I need to add graphs(time-series and a candlestick). after searching I found that [Bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) is best for what I want to achieve.

**Question:**
I want to add time-series and candlestick graph in my Django project.

**Code**
This is how I m predicting stocks closing price on the current day.

`stockprediction.py`

```
def get_stock_data(name):
    try:
        if model_check(name) == False:
            data_path = os.getcwd()+"\\StockPrediction\\data\\HISTORICAL_DATA\\"
            df = pd.read_csv(data_path + name + '_data.csv')
            df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
            X = df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3]]
            Y = df.iloc[:, [4]]

            reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
            reg.fit(X,Y)
            y_today = reg.predict([get_nse_data(name)])

            model_path = os.getcwd() + "\\StockPrediction\\data\\saved_data\\"
            file = model_path + name + ".pkl"
            joblib.dump(reg, file)
            return y_today[0][0]
        else:
            model_path = os.getcwd()+"\\StockPrediction\\data\\saved_data\\"
            file = model_path + name+".pkl"
            model = joblib.load(file)
            y_today = model.predict([get_nse_data(name)])
            return y_today
    except:
        return ("Error")

def get_nse_data(name):
    data = nse.get_quote(name)
    current = [data['open'], data['dayHigh'], data['dayLow']]
    return current
```

**Bonus Question:**
I need graphs which are best for showing stocks price like candlestick and time-series(can you suggest more.)
Help!

Comment: Did my response below help at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement Bokeh, you can set up everything using the steps in the documentation (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#userguide-quickstart) and that will generate your .html file which you can include in your templates folder.
However, I find libraries like chart.js much more handy and customizable. They can be implemented in django fairly easily. Here's a link to a very good tutorial that helped me  a lot:
https://youtu.be/B4Vmm3yZPgc

Answer (score 0):

I've found holoviews to be really nice for this kind of stuff - in your case, you want to work with RangeToolLink in conjunction with hv.Curve and a pandas dataframe to make a typical stock plot with a range tool on the bottom.

Here's a simple example, stolen from [the holoviews website:](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/timeseries_range_tool.html)

```
import bokeh
bokeh.sampledata.download() # only needs to run once
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL
from holoviews.plotting.links import RangeToolLink
from holoviews import opts

hv.extension('bokeh')

# Make dataframe from stock data
aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL['close'], columns=['close'], index=pd.to_datetime(AAPL['date']))
aapl_df.index.name = 'Date'

# Create stock curve
aapl_curve = hv.Curve(aapl_df, 'Date', ('close', 'Price ($)'))
# Labels and layout
tgt = aapl_curve.relabel('AAPL close price').opts(width=800, labelled=['y'], toolbar='disable')
src = aapl_curve.opts(width=800, height=100, yaxis=None, default_tools=[])

RangeToolLink(src, tgt)
# Merge rangetool
layout = (tgt + src).cols(1)
layout.opts(opts.Layout(shared_axes=False, merge_tools=False))
```

Here's what you should see:
[image]

An even simpler example [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html) uses candlesticks in bokeh:

```
from math import pi
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000, title = "MSFT Candlestick")
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

show(p)
```

Result:
[image]

This all works seamlessly in a Jupyter notebook, so it should be easy enough for you - you just need to get your predictions into a Pandas dataframe!